# Passing a parameter that is going to be used as condition in _Navigation.cshtml

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor

I'm new to `MVC 5` and i just want to ask how can i pass a parameter that will be used as a condition inside the _Navigation.cshtml page.

I'm using `Jquery` to redirect to another page but I need to add a parameter for the Shared Navigation page to hide some of the Navigation Link in it

Here is the Button Event in my Index Page that redirects to the Register Page

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function (id) {
        $('.btnCreate').click(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            location.href = '/Account/Register';
        });
    });
</script>
```

should I pass a parameter to the Register page? How can i passed it to Shared _Navigation page? Thanks in advance

Comment: How are you using your 'shared' `_Navigation.cshtml` view? Is that a partial within your layout? And what would the parameter actually do (how do you want to 'hide' links?). You need to give a bit more context.

Comment: @StephenMuecke Yes sir , its  a partial within my layout and I would like to use the parameter like "fromIndex" to and use it as a condition to check if the the buttonclick is from the index page so if its from the index page , i would hide  the 2 Url.Actions

Comment: You could certainly use something like `location.href = '/Account/Register?caller="Index"` and include a parameter in your method - `ActionResult Register(string caller)` and then assign it to a `ViewBag` property - `ViewBag.Caller = caller;` and in the layout use `@if (ViewBag.Caller == "Index") { // hide links }` but there are probably a lot of better ways

Comment: sir @StephenMuecke Thanks sir ! will definitely  try this one sir

Comment: There are better ways to achiev's what you want), then you do not need any javascript - you can just get the caller from the `Request.UrlReferrer`. And you could use an action filter to set the `ViewBag` property (although using a base view model property would be better). Its a bit hard to know when you question is lacking any detail.

Comment: Sir @StephenMuecke thank you for the answer despite the lack of details on my problem. Now it works. Thanks